# Como criar um componente container de outros componentes

Tags: javascript, react, jsx

Boa tarde!

Estou tentando criar um componente que contem divs que estilizam os componentes dentro. Só que são 3 divs e não quero replica-las toda vez que eu for usar, então pensei em criar um componente que guarde elas e me resuma em apenas uma linha todas as 3.

```
export default class Container extends React.Component {
render() {
    return (
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <div className="row">
            <div className = "col-12 mt-3">
              /* INSERIR O CONTEUDO AQUI */
            </div>   
          </div>
        </div>  
    );
  }
}
```

Aonde está inserir conteúdo é aonde deve estar os componentes do que inseri anteriormente, como por exemplo o componente Title.

```
export default class Index extends React.Component {   
render() {
  return (
    <div>
        <MainStyle pageTitle = {"Resumo do Monitoramento"}/>
        <Navbar /> 
        <Container>
          <Title primary="Index" secondary="Página Index" />
        </Container> 
    </div>
   );
  }
}
```

É possível fazer isso em react?

Comment: Não entendi sua pergunta

Answer (score 1):

Se eu entendi corretamente, dentro do seu componente "Index" você importou outros componentes, como o "MainStyle" e o "Container". Esse componente "Container" foi o primeiro que você informou em seu post. Dentro de "Container", você quer inserir outros componentes, em seu exemplo, você quer inserir dentro dele um  outro componente chamado "Title".

Você conseque fazer isso em seu componente "Container" utilizando uma props chamada "children". Seu componente ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
export default class Container extends React.Component {
render() {
    return (
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <div className="row">
            <div className = "col-12 mt-3">
                {this.props.children}
            </div>   
          </div>
        </div>  
    );
  }
}
```

Aqui tem um exemplo:

https://www.freecodecamp.org/forum/t/react-components-rendering-other-components/90336/4

E aqui tem a documentação referente a componentes:

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html